# TailwindCSS: peer-has-[] only work for siblings with peer class appearing before the peer-has-[] element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to style an element based on a class appearing in the descendants of a sibling element. I am able to achieve that if the sibling element happens to appear before the element to be styled in the HTML code, but it does not work if the sibling appears right after it.

Here's a sample code

```
<div>
  <div class="peer/before">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="peer-has-[.active]/before:italic">This works!</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 class="peer-has-[.active]/after:italic">This does not!</h1>
  <div class="peer/after">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a stackblitz to reproduce this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nymz3a?file=src%2Fhello-world%2Fhello-world.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `peer-*` variants by their very nature only work for elements before the class with the `peer-*` modifier attached. This is because `peer` relies on the [CSS subsequent-sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator).

If you need to rely on some element after, you could consider using a [`has-*` variant instead](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-descendants) like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div>
  <h1 class="has-[+.after_.active]:italic">This does not!</h1>
  <div class="after">
    <div class="active"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 class="has-[+.after_.active]:italic">This does not!</h1>
  <div class="after">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```